# Convert date timestamp to string in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I use python 3.8, I have data:

```
dataAll = [(Timestamp('2020-12-13 22:00:00'), 'Test'), (Timestamp('2020-12-13 23:00:00'), 'Test2')]
```

I need to do so:

```
dataAll = [('2020-12-13 22:00:00'), 'Test'), (('2020-12-13 23:00:00'), 'Test2')]
```

Comment: What's `Timestamp`?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what the problem is, but if you want topLine to function as bottomLine

def Timestamp(string):
return string

will produce that so:

dataAll = [(Timestamp('2020-12-13 22:00:00'), 'Test'), (Timestamp('2020-12-13 23:00:00'), 'Test2')]
equivalent to:
dataAll = [(('2020-12-13 22:00:00'), 'Test'), (('2020-12-13 23:00:00'), 'Test2')] # note second "("